# I want to select data in 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, toad

structure table

```
Pk     id <------------| primary Key
       name            |
       country         |
fk     parent_id <-----| forigen key
```

Data

```
id| name    | country    | parent_id
1 | Diva    | Portugal   | 2
2 | Alex    | Georgia    | 2
3 | Bianca  | Palau      | 4
4 | Tony    | Montenegro | 1
```

result

```
id| name    | country    | parent_id | name_parent_id |
1 | Diva    | Portugal   | 2         | Alex           |
2 | Alex    | Georgia    | 2         | Alex           |
3 | Bianca  | Palau      | 4         | Tony           |
4 | Tony    | Montenegro | 1         | Diva           |
```

the result for this case

Any advice on this one?

Comment: Use a correlated subquery.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same table twice in order to select the parent name:

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    c.country,
    c.parent_id,
    p.name AS name_parent_id
FROM
    YourTable AS c
    INNER JOIN YourTable AS p ON c.id = p.parent_id
```

I used `c` as alias for the child and `p` for the parent.
*Note*:  You can use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` in case of the existence of the parent is not required.